# Facebook like / send buttons... the popup boxes are cut-off

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to figure out what CSS I must change to fix this problem: If you visit my site http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/ and click the topmost Facebook like or send, the popup that comes up is cut off and so one cannot see part of it. I want the popup to appear in the normal facebook default width, whatever that is, probably something like 300px or so.

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this iframe.fb_ltr at line 557 of a css file, it's 180px.

```
iframe.fb_ltr {
    width: 180px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something since any solution i have found online wasnt working...

Once you click the like button a class is being added to the iframe... 
that is great and mean you can style the popup only and leave your like button as is.

**Here is the class being added:**

```
.fb_iframe_widget_lift {

}
```

**For example & since my button was in a static footer i added:**

```
.fb_iframe_widget_lift {
overflow: visible !important;
width: 475px !important;
margin-top: -249px;
margin-right: -220px !important;
background: #000;
padding: 10px;
height: 237px !important;
}
```

Using this you can customize the popup as you wish.

Best regards, Sagive.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that when you load FB JavaScript it has APP ID!

For example
//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=77777777777

If you will not have appId at the end it won't load scripts that expand comment box.